# batch to deactivate LAN and activate WLAN

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I am trying to make a batch script to switch between LAN and WLAN every time it's launched, but it's seems i have a problem somewhere.

Here is my script:

```
@Echo off


if errorlevel 1 goto LAN
if errorlevel 0 goto WLAN

:LAN

netsh interface set interface "Connexion réseau sans fil 2" disabled 

netsh interface set interface "Connexion au réseau local 3" enabled 

goto end

:WLAN

netsh interface set interface "Connexion au réseau local 3" disabled

netsh interface set interface "Connexion réseau sans fil 2" enabled
start chrome.exe

:END
```

When i launch this script i got this:

```
L'interface portant ce nom n'est pas enregistrée pour le routeur.

L'interface portant ce nom n'est pas enregistrée pour le routeur.
```

Which mean that this interface having this name is not registered on the router

probably it will be an encoding problem as u can see the network interface name is in french...but i don't know...

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  Is there an error message?

Comment: sorry i add it to the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem here, using a pt_br Windows version. Try to use "copy con " and type your commands directly at the prompt. Press Ctrl+Z to save and exit. Voilà! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the codepage with the CP command so that the French text is recognised correctly.